# How to hide or change the path to the images in Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading images in Amazon S3 bucket , I want to morph the url of the image or change it with the domain name ,how to do map the url of bucket with custom domain?

Comment: Could you please edit your Question to provide more details of what you wish to achieve? For example, are you saying that you wish the content of your S3 bucket to be available via a custom domain name? Have you read [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) for that. CloudFront lets you use your own domain name (for example, www.example.com) for links to your objects instead of using the domain name that CloudFront assigns to your distribution.

You can read more [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html).